# auto populate fields in a form

Tags: 2007

is it possible to auto populate fields in a form without using infopath?

example:

user chooses (a) in field 1.

this choice auto populates fields 1 and 2.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go take a a look at SPServices.  Marc has done a great job and I have used this to achieve the cascade relationship  you are after.  You can put the script in a Content Editor Web Part on the custom form that you will create in Designer(easiest way to go IMHO) and set the list to this new form that you created.

[link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that I've used in the past. It works. Any solution is going to require some javascript (although there was a way in 2003 to do it with built-in variables).

http://kitmenke.com/blog/2010/03/11/autopopulate-a-sharepoint-form-from-url/

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use telerik RadComboBox control. to auto populate data.